# magento 2.0: set session variable

Tags: php, magento2

I want to set a session variable in a custom module.

I am using 
 `$_SESSION['product_id'] = "12";` in the custom module's controller.

When I try to get this session in the `configurable.phtml` template it fails to find right value.

Please let me know how to properly set a session variable, and how to read this session value again in the template using Magento 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is the block class.

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Block;
class YourModule extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    protected $_catalogSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,     
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCatalogSession() 
    {
        return $this->_catalogSession;
    }   
}
?>
```

Now, we set and get session from template (.phtml) file.

```
// set product id in catalog session
$block->getCatalogSession()->setProductId(12);

// get product id from catalog session
echo $block->getCatalogSession()->getProductId();

// unset session variable
$block->getCatalogSession()->unsProductId();
```

Comment: Can i apply two session in one class like checkout & catalog session?